# image control in asp.net (<img> element) -> inside image positioning help !

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, image, background-position

i have an image component in asp.net like below :

```
<div id="imgOperatorLogoContainer">
    <asp:Image ID="imgOperatorLogo" runat="server" ToolTip="bla bla"
                AlternateText="bla bla" ImageUrl="~/Images/c"
                Width="170px" Height="191px" />
</div>
```

as you see i put width and height for this image , but by doing this face-images.jpg (3*170 = 510 * 191) is stretched in the  element area!
but i do n't want this act , because face-images.jpg contains 3 images (170*191) inside and i want to control their positioning with css and jquery!
i know we can do this job by a div element - > but what about an image component of asp.net!
that image after render like below (html)  :

```
<img style="height: 191px; width: 170px;" alt="bla bla" src="Images/face-images.jpg" title="bla bla" id="imgOperatorLogo">
```

but why the below css s do not work for this image :

```
#imgOperatorLogo
{
  background-position: 0px 0px;
}
```

or

```
#imgOperatorLogo
{
  background-position: -170px 0px;
}
```

or

```
#imgOperatorLogo
{
  background-position: -340px 0px;
}
```

we can fix this issue by an alternate div -> but in this way we lose alt text and i think that is important for **SEO**
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

First image:

```
<div id="imgOperatorLogoContainer" style="width: 170px; height: 191px;
    background: url(Images/logo.png) 0 0;">
</div>
```

Second image:

```
<div id="imgOperatorLogoContainer" style="width: 170px; height: 191px;
    background: url(Images/logo.png) -170px 0;">
</div>
```

Third image:

```
<div id="imgOperatorLogoContainer" style="width: 170px; height: 191px;
    background: url(Images/logo.png) -340px 0;">
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for answer / i know we can fix this issue by div s or something like that , but how can i fix it by using image component ? or how can i add AlternateText to these div s (text that appears before image loading)?

Answer (score 0):

Is the same... The IMG controls renders an ID that can be used via jQuery using the # selector or you can use the CssClass that renders a class and use the . selector

Comment: thanks for attention ...i don't have any problem about css or jquery / my problem is how can i remove that stretched act?

Comment: Do not add the Width and Height

Comment: by doing this we will see all of those 3 images without stretching ... btw we can not control their positioning with css!

Comment: dear @HiperiX : did u get my meaning?

Comment: Based on the answer... I say you did was a sprite (I didn't know what you where meaning) http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites

Answer (score 0):

take a look into css sprites..

ok first of all, which ¨below¨ comment are you referring to? secondly, when you want it to render like an  tag why would you try and put a style for background-image on it? And you wanna add alternate text? you can generate image tags with jquery with styles suggested above with alt-text attr, or just add title attr. or do you want it to stop from stretching(since you seem to know the size), just add your own width and height..and how DO you wanna display it? three separate images? You don´t wanna use DIVs and you wanna display them in one ASP.Net Image control that has the size of one of the three images? what do you want?

Comment: which comment? mean -> @HiperiX thanks for attention ...i don't have any problem about css or jquery!  / why would you try and put a style for background-image on it? -> plz do it by your self and remove ImageUrl from that image control! u will see AlternateText In fornt of that background-image... / You don´t wanna use DIVs and you wanna display them in one ASP.Net Image control that has the size of one of the three images? -> yes , i just want to learn how can i do this by one [image control] and control it's image positioning with jquery and css , just learning.